# Remove or Refresh DataTable

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable

I am running into issues with an application that I wrote.  Basically it is a month calendar that is made out of panels/listboxes for each day of the month. I populate my listboxes using the following:

```
private void PopulateEventListBoxes(int offsetNumber, int monthDays)
{
    string locationSelected = this.LocationComboBox.Text.ToLower();

    for (int i = 0; i <= (monthDays - 1); i++)
    {
        DateTime dateSelected = Convert.ToDateTime(m_ArrayDateLabel[offsetNumber + i].Text).Date;

        var tempCalendar = new Data.DataSet.vwGet_CalendarDetailsDataTable();

        switch (locationSelected)
        {
            case "all":
                Data.Manager.CalendarDetailsTableAdapter.FillByDate(tempCalendar, dateSelected);
                break;
            default:
                Data.Manager.CalendarDetailsTableAdapter.FillByDateCity(tempCalendar, dateSelected, locationSelected);
                break;
        }

        foreach (Data.DataSet.vwGet_CalendarDetailsRow row in tempCalendar)
        {
            ((ListBox)m_ArrayEventListBox[offsetNumber + i]).Items.Add(row.Name + " - " + row.StatusCode);
        }
    }
}
```

I am using the `var tempCalendar = new Data.DataSet.vwGet_CalendarDetailsDataTable();` for the DataTable because I need to load the day events into each of the listboxes. This data is coming from SQL server from a view.

Once the Calendar loaded, the users have the ability to Add/Edit/Delete items through a pop-up Dialog with the Calendar details for the day.  When the Dialog loads to Add/Edit I populate it this way:

```
private void SearchForEventsByDate()
{
    switch (m_LocationSelected)
    {
        case "all":
            Data.Manager.CalendarDetailsTableAdapter.FillByDate(DataSetCalendar.vwGet_CalendarDetails, m_DateSelected);
            CalendarDetailsBindingSource.DataSource = DataSetCalendar.vwGet_CalendarDetails;
            break;
        default:
            Data.Manager.CalendarDetailsTableAdapter.FillByDateCity(DataSetCalendar.vwGet_CalendarDetails, m_DateSelected, m_LocationSelected);
            CalendarDetailsBindingSource.DataSource = DataSetCalendar.vwGet_CalendarDetails;
            break;
    }

    RefreshRepRecordCount();
}
```

This time when load the data, I am using the call `DataSetCalendar.vwGet_CalendarDetails` instead of a temp memory version of the datatable.

My issue is coming into play if I follow these procedures:

1. Add new event for an employee
2. Delete that same event that I just added
3. Try and re-add new event for the employee on the same day - the app throws an error that the GUID is already present in the table.

My table's primary key is EventDate and EmployeeGuid.  If I query the SQL table after the delete, there is no record but my application still thinks the record still exists.  I know that the record is in the memory.

I have tried the following to remove it from memory but it is not working:

```
DataSetCalendar.vwGet_CalendarDetails.FindByEmployeeGUID(SelectedCalendarEvent.EmployeeGUID).Delete();
DataSetCalendar.vwGet_CalendarDetails.AcceptChanges();
```

I have also tried using `Remove` to get rid of the record but my app still think the record exists.  I don't know what else to do or try.  Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by adding the `Clear()`

```
private void SearchForEventsByDate()
{
    switch (m_LocationSelected)
    {
       case "all":
         Data.Manager.Data.SM_T_Employee_Status.Clear();
         DataSetCalendar.vwGet_CalendarDetails.Clear();

         Data.Manager.CalendarDetailsTableAdapter.FillByDate(DataSetCalendar.vwGet_CalendarDetails, m_DateSelected);
          CalendarDetailsBindingSource.DataSource = DataSetCalendar.vwGet_CalendarDetails;
          break;
       default:
          Data.Manager.Data.SM_T_Employee_Status.Clear();
          DataSetCalendar.vwGet_CalendarDetails.Clear();
          Data.Manager.CalendarDetailsTableAdapter.FillByDateCity(DataSetCalendar.vwGet_CalendarDetails, m_DateSelected, m_LocationSelected);
          CalendarDetailsBindingSource.DataSource = DataSetCalendar.vwGet_CalendarDetails;
          break;
     }

 RefreshRepRecordCount();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you "storing" the calendar on the client side? Knowing that will lead you to the answer. It sounds like you have some type of cache on the client side.

If you cache on the client side, you need to refresh the cache when you change data on the server side.

Comment: Not to sound dumb, but I am not 100% sure.  We are using a winforms template/framework that was created by someone in my dept.  I am still pretty new to how the whole thing works.  But I know that I have to refresh it in the memory but I haven't been able to successfully do it.

Comment: Asking questions is an indication of not being dumb, as dumb people do not ask questions. The unfortunate thing, at least in many implementations, about homegrown frameworks is abstractions are not thought through. If the cahcing method is encapsulated, you will have to dig through the framework and determine how to invalidate the cache.